# magento 1.8 urls WITHOUT category code 12-15s WITH category code 1s

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have been banging my head with this for 2 solid days, playing with apc cache, my.cnf, http settings etc... thinking there was some server config error.

Anyway I have nailed the issue down to urls that have a trailing ?cat=xxxx and those that don't.

On first request the server takes at least 12s to deliver the first bytecode of a catalogue category if it doesn't have the trailing ?cat=xxxx, the same url with this param delivers in 1s.

Subsequent requests also deliver in 1s but this is obviously the cache kicking in.

during this 12s delay I am in mysql console looking for process list and nothing. It appears to be in the PHP stack.

I have 2 gig of ram and have given php 500M

here are the biggies from the profiler:

mage::dispatch::routers_match - 12s
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view - 12s
layout/db_update: STORE_default     11.9965
layout/db_update: THEME_frontend_default_default    11.9952
layout/db_update: catalog_category_view   11.9938
ayout/db_update: MAP_popup  11.9674
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_popup    11.9659
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup 11.9644 
layout/db_update: catalog_category_layered  11.9634
layout/db_update: CATEGORY_1513 11.9621 
layout/db_update: customer_logged_out   11.9603

REWRITE: Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Url::getCategoryUrl  1.6975  2741  16,165,328  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view::layout_render    11.8676
frontend/base/default/template/page/3columns.phtml  11.6791

frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml  10.8389 1   45,467,392  46,661,632
DISPATCH EVENT:page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before   10.1428 1   42,748,696  44,040,192
OBSERVER: catalog_add_topmenu_items 10.1426 1

as you can probably see I am using the default theme.

So the links of the top navigation take ages, then the pinned blocks on the left (which have the ?cat=xxxx url param) are instant.

Now obviously I could fix it by adding the ?cat=xxxx into the main navigation, but really I would like to know what the hell is the cause of all my past 2 days of headache.

Anyone who can help?

Many thanks

Richard.

Comment: Ok update, the quick pages dont seem to call the topmenu code...?

I guess this leaves the question why are pages without ?cat=xxxx causing the top menu to be re-written?

Comment: Well as it turned out, the menu which I want to keep has upto 3 or 4 submenus and it churns out to be neary 500K of html. rather that let magento build this each time, I put the static html into the template, it's not going to change much and when it does I can edit the template. The site is flying now 1s pages all the time...

still surprised that building this menu took a good 11secs or more in magento - what a bottleneck....

Comment: The header (navigation) in Magento can become a real showstopper when it gets populated with too many categories. For these kind of situations, I mostly replace the navigation with an active one, and highlight the correct active item with JavaScript

Comment: Dear Rich, I have the same problem with my 1.9 Magento. We do have like 50 categories with up to 3-4 sub cats. We have loading times of +9 seconds. On a server with 32 Gigs RAM and 10 Cores, I expect a bit more :) Which advise could you give me for that problem?